# Xquery - function to transform xml special characters (ie. from &lt; to < )

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In Xquery 3.1 (in eXist-db) I am receiving XML content in an API call converted to text like this:

```
<content zapi:type="tei" type="text/xml">&lt;?xml 
   version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;listBibl 
    xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"&gt;&lt;/listBibl&gt;</content>
```

I want to parse the `text()` of the `content` node and store/manipulate it as an XML document. I can only think of using a series of nested `replace()` functions (and then storing it as a document node).

Is there a more elegant function (in Xquery or eXist) that converts these reserved character encodings back into XML format?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Bookmark the XPath 3.1 function spec, it has a `parse-xml` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-xml

Comment: That works great (and thanks for the link). Thankfully the version of eXist I use supports XPath 3.1.

Comment: @MartinHonnen that should be an answer...

Comment: @MichaelKay, I have converted the suggestion from the comment into an answer, was not sure about eXist and also not sure whether the posted sample really represented well-formed XML so that `parse-xml` would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for a particular function available in XQuery 3 or XSLT 3 the first place to look should be the common XPath 3.1 functions spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/. Max Toro's compilation at https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/ might be a more compact representation to start with.

XPath 3 and later has a `parse-xml` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-xml that parses a string of XML into a document node.

Comment: Thanks for the additional references - that helps a lot!